# In PL/SQL, how do I use a varaible in a SELECT *without* using an INTO?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm experimenting with queries in an Oracle database (Using Oracle SQl Developer and PL/SQL Developer)

If I run a simple query: (`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 1234`) the results display in a nice grid in a lower pane of the SQL tool.

Now, how do I rewrite that query, using a variable for the `1234`, And STILL have the results spill out into the results pane.  Everything I've tried either won't compile, or requires me to do a `SELECT...INTO` and then manually output the results.

I just want to do something along the lines of this, and have it work:

```
 DECLARE p0 = 1234;
 SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = p0;
```

UPDATE:
In the actual query I'm working on, the variables will be more like:

```
 DECLARE p0 = to_date('1/15/2014 7:11:05 AM','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM');
         p1 = p0 + .0007; -- one minute later.
```

So being able to write that in code is important.

Comment: Use `:p0` instead of `p0`

Comment: Using `:p0` has it ask me the value to use in a pop-up dialog box, instead of using the value in the code.

Answer (score 3):

In Toad (or sqlplus or SQL Developer) you would do:

```
define x='20140820';
select to_date(&x, 'YYYYMMDD') from dual;
```

And run as a Script (important).

In Toad, the Output grid would be:

```
old: select to_date(&x, 'YYYYMMDD') from dual
new: select to_date(20140820, 'YYYYMMDD') from dual

TO_DATE(20140820,'YYYYMMDD')
----------------------------
20-AUG-2014                 
1 row selected.
```

And Grid1 would just show the results in table grid format.

Note that you can suppress the old/new in output by doing:

```
set verify off
```

at top of script.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to create a bind variable named `cur`, for example, of type `REFCURSOR`, use `OPEN :cur FOR SELECT ...` in your PL/SQL block and then `PRINT` the cursor out.  Here's an example with a very simple query:

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR

BEGIN
  OPEN :cur FOR SELECT * FROM DUAL;
END;
/

PRINT cur
```

This works in SQL*Plus and SQL Developer, although in the latter it will only work if you use the 'Run Script (F5)' button, not the 'Run Statement (Ctrl+Enter)' button.  Also, you don't get a table with the results in, just the query output in preformatted text.  Also,  it won't necessarily work in other tools, as `VARIABLE` and `PRINT` are not part of SQL nor PL/SQL - SQL*Plus and SQL Developer both understand them and can interpret them.

In PL/SQL Developer you can use a Test Window for this kind of thing.  For example, enter into a Test Window a PL/SQL block such as

```
BEGIN
  OPEN :cur FOR SELECT * FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Then, either add the variable `cur` of type 'Cursor' to the variables table at bottom of the window, (or choose Scan Variables from the context menu.  Note that PL/SQL Developer won't necessarily get the type right; you may well still have to change the type.  Once you run the block, the results from the cursor can be obtained in a separate window by clicking the '...' button in the row in the variables table for `cur`.

Answer (score 0):

As a minor variation on Luke's excellent answer, you don't even need a ref cursor if you just want to display a variable's value. Put this in a Test window:

```
declare
    p0 date := to_date('1/15/2014 7:11:05 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM');
begin
    :p1 := p0 + .0007;
end;
```

then set up the `p1` bind variable in the lower panel. Executing it will display the value.